# Checking injectivity of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $C = \{ \underline{x} = (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = 1, |z| \leq 1 \} $

let $M = \{ \{ \underline{x}, - \underline{x} \} : \underline{x} \in C \} $ and consider $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ such that

$$ f: \{ \underline{x}, - \underline{x} \} \to ( (x^2 -y^2)(2+xz) , \;  2xy(2 + xz), \; yz ) $$

My question is: Is there a fast way to check this function for injectivity? faster than the usual way to show injectivity?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize $C$ by $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta, z)$ with $\theta$ real and $|z| \leq 1$. The portion with $0 \leq \theta < \pi$ maps bijectively to $M$, and in these coordinates,
$$
f(\theta, z) = \bigl(\cos(2\theta)(2 + z\cos\theta), \sin(2\theta)(2 + z\cos\theta), z\sin\theta\bigr).
$$
Since $r := 2 + z\cos\theta > 0$ for all $(\theta, z)$, the point $f(\theta, z)$ lies in the open half-plane through the $z$-axis making angle $2\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis. These half-planes are disjoint for distinct $\theta$ in $[0, \pi)$, so if $f(\theta_1, z_1) = f(\theta_2, z_2)$, then $\theta_1 = \theta_2$. It now follows easily that $z_1 = z_2$ as well.